# Running Command from within ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an itemsControl that is populated from an ObservableCollection.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableSessions}" Margin="490,181,10.111,39.111">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border  BorderBrush="Black" Background="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2">
                <!-- This is the Inner Grid for each element, which is represented in 
                 Brown color in your picture -->
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="134"  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="263" Background="#FFECECEC">
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243" Height="42" Command="{Binding 
                      OpenSessionCommand, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"><Run Text="{Binding SessionName}"/>                                                 
                       <LineBreak/><Run Text="{Binding Genre}"/><Run Text=" - "/>
                       <Run Text="{Binding Tempo}"/><Run Text=" BPM"/><LineBreak/>
                    </TextBlock>
                    </Button>
                    <Label Content="{Binding SessionName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                      Margin="10,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243" 
                      Height="26"/>
                    <Label Content="Drummmman - Electronic Drums"                         
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,71,0,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243" Height="25"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

When I click the OpenSessionCommand button nothing happens.  This works fine when I bind it outside of the ItemsControl.  Do I have to add this command as a property inside the observablecollection?  Or is there a way to specify a binding inside ItemsSource to a binding in the parent grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the ItemsSource for the ItemsControl is set, so that is where your binding is deriving from.  Simply use a Relative Source like so:

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.OpenSessionCommand}"/>
```

In place of window put the element that contains the Data Context you would like to access, in your case Grid.

Comment: That makes sense, however I'm still getting a design error saying "Cannot resolve MainChatViewModel in App.Views.MainChatView"  When I run the project nothing happens on button click